# How to manage almost concurrent threads in RoR 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hoping someone can help me clarify the question itself. Not an expert at all in programming.

Until about 2 months ago incoming requests to my RoR app would (I think) be ran sequentially.

I have a lot of after_remove, before_remove,after_add actions for some of those requests.

Since the beginning of the year errors started popping up about ids being already taken, and external resources would be created twice because of incoming requests coming in for the same resource while the first was not finished processing.

Was there a change recently in the way requests are handled in RoR that I can turn off, other than simply going back to the previous rails versions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you update something? if so, what?

Comment: Any chance you just scaled up you app? But anyhow, you'll have to rollback or fix your code or add some locks.